# Adding Wordpress function into shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode `[table id=table /]`

I want to do something like this `<?php echo do_shortcode('[table id="'.$post->post_name.'"/]'); ?>`

I want the slug to appear as the table id.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to add the short code in the functions.php file of your theme. Does this work for you?

Comment: What do I need to add to the function file exactly? I'm trying to get this to display in a widget.

Comment: How did you go with this @suge1w?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you mentioned in the comments that you're trying to use this shortcode in a widget - widgets don't parse shortcodes by default.

To make most widgets parse shortcodes (*most* being those with text fields that apply the `widget_text` filter), you can add the following to your theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter("widget_text", "do_shortcode");
```

You can then refer to this shortcode directly in your widget text like you would expect you can:

```
[table id=... /]
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have any trouble running shortcodes that are on their own line, it may be because they get wrapped in `<p></p>` tags automatically by Wordpress. To stop this happening, add this filter *before* the one added above:

```
add_filter("widget_text", "shortcode_unautop");
```

The [shortcode_unautop()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_unautop/) function simply stops shortcodes from being wrapped in paragraph tags like is Wordpress' default behaviour in most text fields.